# WPF How to show main window, that is hidden, from sub window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using c# WPF. I hide the main window and open a new sub window. Now I want to turn back to my main window that is hidden before.

I hide my main window and open my sub window with this code:

```
this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
MovingObjectWindow movingObjectWindow = new 
MovingObjectWindow();
movingObjectWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: I would use the `movingObjectWindow.ShowDialog()` _(instead of he movingObjectWindow.Visibility)_  put the `this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;` behind it. The ShowDialog is modal, meaning that it will block the current method until you close it.

Comment: As another note, try to limit the amount of switching windows/opening modal dialogs etc - it gets user easily confused, especially if you allow more than 1 instance of the app. Instead opening new window, change the content of the current window. This is done with Pages or UserControls, they are more or less the same thing, but Pages already have navigation service built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to your subwindow's closed event to open back your main window. 
Add this after you call your subwindow constructor :

```
movingObjectWindow.Closed += (sender, args) => { this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; };
```

Comment: sender gives me this error: A local or parameter named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Comment: About the error you got, you can just rename the variable _sender_ in _s_ or whatever you want : this is just the name of one of the lambda expression's parameters.

Comment: you are not very clear about **when** you want to open back your main window. I assumed it was when you closed your subwindow.

Comment: that works, thanks. Now can I change it by movingObjectWindow.Hidden or something like it? I want my main window to be opened when I hide my sub window

Comment: **Hidden** is not an event but a property, so you cannot subscribe a function to call to it. But you could do something like : `movingObjectWindow.IsVisibleChanged += (s, args) => { if (movingObjectWindow.IsVisible == false) { this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; } };`

Answer (score 0):

You can access your MainWinodowInstance like this:

```
(Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: I get this error: System.NullReferenceException. (... as Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.KinectFusionExplorer.MainWindow) returned null.

Comment: I create sub window with a button. If i put MovingObjectWindow movingObjectWindow = new MovingObjectWindow(); to the inside of button click function, the code you said works, but i need to put it to outside of the button click function because I don't want to create new windows everytime